# Merging two multidimensional lists

Tags: python, list

I have 2 multidimensional lists:

```
lst1 = [['test1','test2','test3'],['test4','test5','test6']]

lst2 = [['column1'],['column2']]
```

You need to combine these 2 lists into one to get:

Output:

```
lst3 = [['test1','test2','test3','column1'],['test4','test5','test6','column2']]
```

There can be different numbers of elements in list1 , numbers of elements list2 corresponds to lst1
There is always one element in the internal list2 list

```
lst1 = [['test1','test2'],['test4','test5']
lst2 = [['column1'],['column2']]
```

Output:

```
lst3 = [['test1','test2','column1'],['test4','test5','column2']]
```

I tried this option, but it is not correct

```
[q + w[0:] for q in lst2 for w in lst1 if w[len(w)-1 ] == q[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this:

```
lst1 = [['test1','test2','test3'],['test4','test5','test6']]
lst2 = [['column1'],['column2']]
```

1. Using for with range:

   ```
   [lst1[i]+lst2[i] for i in range(len(lst2))]
   ```
2. Using zip function like mentioned above in comments by @001
3. Use map function:

   ```
   list(map(lambda x, y: x + y, lst1, lst2))
   ```

Comment: Zip has not been used before. Thanks everything works.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst1 = [['test1','test2','test3'],['test4','test5','test6']]
lst2 = [['column1'],['column2']]

lst3 = [x + y for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2)]
print(lst3)
```

This code creates a new list lst3 by iterating over two lists lst1 and lst2 in parallel using the zip() function. For each element of lst1 and lst2, it concatenates them using the + operator and appends the result to lst3. The resulting lst3 will have the desired format:

```
[['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'column1'], ['test4', 'test5', 'test6', 'column2']]
```